# How can I apply a function to remove specific characters on a column of a dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, dataset

I want to apply a function that loops on a column of a dataset that contains text articles. The articles are in Arabic, so I want to remove every symbol and the entire English alphabet. It's a text cleaning for Arabic articles.

I created a loop to replace specific characters with an empty value.
When I try to apply it, I get an error said ***AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'***

Here is the code with a screenshot of the error:

```
var = d['Text']

def cleaning(var):
    to_delete_characters = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz“”ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&*()_+-""=\|/?.,><;]:[؟،"
    for character in to_delete_characters:
        var = var.replace(character, "")
    return var

var.apply(func_name)
```

The error screenshot link:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NWq2.png)

The dataset screenshot link:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZqCf.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not just do this one liner:

```
to_delete_characters = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz“”ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&*()_+-""=\|/?.,><;]:[؟،"
var = d['Text'].astype(str).str.replace('|'.join(to_delete_characters)))
```

Or try:

```
var = d['Text'].astype(str)

def cleaning(var):
    to_delete_characters = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz“”ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&*()_+-""=\|/?.,><;]:[؟،"
    for character in to_delete_characters:
        var = var.replace(character, "")
    return var

var.apply(func_name)
```

**Edit:**

To remove multiple whitespace, try:

```
to_delete_characters = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz“”ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&*()_+-""=\|/?.,><;]:[؟،"
var = d['Text'].astype(str).str.replace('|'.join(to_delete_characters))).str.replace('\s+', ' ')
```

Or try:

```
import re
d['Text'] = d['Text'].astype(str)
def cleaning(var):
    to_delete_characters = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz“”ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&*()_+-""=\|/?.,><;]:[؟،"
    for character in to_delete_characters:
        var = re.sub('\s+', ' ', var.replace(character, ""))
    return var

d['Text'] = d['Text'].apply(func_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, I'd recommend using `str.maketrans` and `str.translate`:

```py
trans = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(to_delete_characters, None))
d["Text"].str.translate(trans)
```

This *should* work, but I don't have an Arabic keyboard to test. It'll also be much faster than the iterative method suggested in the other answer.

EDIT: you may need to convert NaNs to empty strings first, I'm not sure how Pandas will handle NaNs in `DataFrame.str.translate`. I'd also recommend in the future providing test data for users answering your question.

Comment: @AhmadSham I suggest at least looking at my answer, as it'll likely be much faster than U12's.

Comment: Dear Sir,
I appreciate your effort, but I didn't know how to apply that actually :(

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the exact variable names you use. You should just be able to copy-paste my solution.